# Can not read embedded objects with JDO on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have two simple Pojos User and Rating. User has an embedded list of ratings.
The classes are annoted with @PersistenceCapable and the proprties with @Persistent.
I wrote a simple test that creates a User, sets ratings and persists it with

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
pm.makePersistent(user);
```

When I fetch the object like this ratings is null (not as I expected):

```
User user = (User) pm.getObjectById(User.class, key);
```

I tried some things to solve the problem:

When I annote the property ratings in User with @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true") the list contains an object with a key, parentkey etc. but the value is never set (resulting in 0.0 instead of the actual value).

I could solve the problem by additionally setting a transaction before persisting the data:

```
pm.currentTransaction().begin();
pm.makePersistent(user);
pm.currentTransaction().commit();
```

So finally it works with the annotation and the transaction. But why is it? 
The behaviour is the same in local unit tests (with the test helper), dev mode and deployed on app engine.

I am using App Engine SDK 1.8.1.
For reference here are User, Rating and the test:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  // if added ratings is fetched
  @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
  private List<Rating> ratings;

  public Key getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(Key key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public List<Rating> getRatings() {
    return ratings;
  }

  public void setRatings(List<Rating> ratings) {
    this.ratings = ratings;
  }
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Rating {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  @Persistent
  private double rating;

  public Key getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(Key key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public double getRating() {
    return rating;
  }

  public void setRating(double rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
  }
}

@Test
  public void testFindByIdWithExistingKey() throws DaoException {

    User user = new User();
    List<Rating> ratings = new ArrayList<Rating>();
    Rating rating = new Rating();
    rating.setRating(1.2);
    ratings.add(rating);
    user.setRatings(ratings);

    Key key = persist(user);

    User user2 = dao.findById(key);
    Assert.assertEquals(1.2, user2.getRatings().get(0).getRating(), 0.0001);
  }

private Key persist(User user) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
      //pm.currentTransaction().begin();
      pm.makePersistent(user);
      //pm.currentTransaction().commit();
      return user.getKey();
    } finally {
      pm.close();
    }
  }

@Override   
public User findById(Key key) throws DaoException {

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
      User user = (User) pm.getObjectById(User.class, key);
      return user;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      throw new DaoException("could not find user", e);
    } finally {
      pm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not look at Google's own tests and compare ? https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus